# Помогите решить проблему с Tab'ами

Tags: javascript, html, scss

У меня есть 18 карточек с товаром, завернутые в grid-сетку.
Какая задача: при загрузке страницы видим 9 карточек, снизу кнопки 1 и 2. и соответственно переключаем этими кнопка карточку с 1-9 и 10-18. все, что я смог сделать, это только открытие 10-18 карточек при нажатии на вторую кнопку, но при нажатии на 1 кнопку все остается на своих местах, не менясь.
Мои знания в js  на данный момент весьма слабоваты, поэтому прошу помощи здесь.
Код по ссылке:   `codepen.io/Nikita-Dev94/pen/ZEjeavo`

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)